# Fortran, type checking shared library

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack

The fortran compiler catches a lot of my stupid mistakes like providing the wrong number of arguments, or some argument that has the wrong type.

However, I use LAPACK and BLAS a lot, and when I make those mistakes when calling their subroutines, gfortran happily compiles it for me, resulting in errors that are hard to debug.

Is there a way to have gfortran check the calls to those shared libraries for me?

I compile using the following commands

```
gfortran -o foo.o -c foo.f
gfortran -o bar bar.f foo.o -lblas -llapack
```

Comment: One solution is to write a module of your own which contains the interfaces for the routines you are using, and USE that in the scoping unit that does the call. These may well exists already - I haven't searched

Comment: simple and effective, i love it